# Jquery struts2 getting results meanwhile typing the search

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

I've been trying for the last 2 days to make a search method, where meanwhile I'm typing, i want to see the different available results for that search (in my iterator). As example: I have different products in my bbdd and I want the user to check for them, even searching.

I have tryed with autocompleter and getting the param term in my action, but after that, when I modify my List products, the results in the iterator don't change.

Products_user.jsp

```
<html>
<s:url var="remoteurl" action="products"></s:url>
<sj:autocompleter href="%{remoteurl}"  label="Search Product By Name"
                  list="products" name="product_auto" listKey="name" 
    />    


       <ul>
        <s:iterator value="products">
                <li>
                    <p> 
                        <s:text name="text.name"/> <s:property value="name"/>                           
                        <s:url id="detalles" action="editProducts">
                            <s:param name="id_product"><s:property value="id"/></s:param>
                        </s:url>
                        <a href="<s:property value="%{detalles}"/>">  <s:text name="field.details"/> </a> &nbsp;                      
                    </p>  
                </li>
        </s:iterator>        

        </ul>
```

showProducts Action

```
public String execute() throws Exception{ 

  DAOFactory SQLFactory;
    SQLFactory = DAOFactory.getDAOFactory(DAOFactory.SQL);

    ProductDAO productDAO = SQLFactory.getProductDAO();
    products = productDAO.get_all_products();


    if(term!=null){ 
        for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {

                        if (StringUtils.startsWith(products.get(i).getName().toLowerCase(), term.toLowerCase()))
                        {
                            products_aux.add(products.get(i));
                        }


                }

    }

    return "success";
```

}

I have tryed this way but I couldn't refresh the results meanwhile the user was typing, hope someone give me a hint, thanks!

Comment: Check out the code in [the showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action) (under widgets -> autocompleter) and in the [official docs](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag). I suggest you to use JSON btw.

Comment: I'm trying to do that but I don't need a "form", neither a submit because a I want to refresh my iterator meanwhile the user is typing a product(if he writes the first letter "c" and there are 3 products starting with "c", I want to show those information about the 3 products instantly in the iterator

Comment: `I'm trying to do that but I don't need a "form", neither a submit` I've not talked about forms nor submits. Take a look at the provided link. All the other things you are saying are called Autocompleter. An autocompleter not "refreshing meanwhile" is not an autocompleter.

Comment: I was checking this "http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action" but still, I can't get it. They don't use any Action class for getting the value of the autocompleter?

Comment: I just want to modify my variable "products" with the possible match results of products according to the letter typed

Comment: 1) Of course they use an Action for getting the values; 2) you can't because struts tags are evaluated server side, while the autocompleter is working client side, with AJAX calls to server side.

Comment: okay, Where can i find the action in the 'showcase' page? Thanks for the answers

Comment: In the second link I provided in the first comment. BTW you simply need to expose a String[] from your action... as I suppose you are already doing. Read the official docs carefully, then try and let us know

Comment: I have a List of products which is read in the autocompleter and the one which is read in the iterator. I read it lot of times but still I'm a bit lost, sorry

Comment: JSP tags are executed on the server. JS/Ajax is executed on the client. If you want to change the DOM after JS activity then you need to handle that via JS on the client side.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all the answers